# Possible to build Xamarin Android on Windows Server Core?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, msbuild

I am going to create an ephemeral Windows Server Core image to use as a build environment which gets recreated each time (a la Vagrant), but didn't want to spend too much time if the Xamarin Android components won't build on a Windows Server Core environment.

Can I install just the MSBuild target files and build tools for Xamarin (Android) without a GUI? If not, can I install the Xamarin Studio and use that on the Windows Server Core image? What is the best approach?

Ideally, I only want to install the bare minimum on the build environment, so no Visual Studios, just MSBuild (from the .NET runtime), Java SDK etc.

Comment: If you found nobody talked about it, you know you will be the first one to experiment that.

Comment: I doubt in this day and age I'm the first to attempt anything :-/

Comment: I believe AppVeyor knows the answer, but that's their trade secrets if I am not wrong.